# Without removing i would like to subset the rows in the dataframe and run an ifelse through the subset?

Tags: r, if-statement

```
{df %>% filter(value %in% list)}$GOOD_Outcome<-ifelse(
                           df$column1 =="Y"&
                           df$column2 !="N"&
                           df$column3!=""&
                           df$column4 !="N"&
                           df$column5 !="",
                         "Yes", "No")
```

I get an error message

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, GOOD_OUTCOME, value = c("No", "No", "No",  :
```

replacement has 977 rows, data has 33

I want the script to disregard the 944 other rows and run the ifelse within the confines of the 33 rows. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your lhs and rhs should have the same length i.e. create an index `i1 <- df$value %in% yourvec`; `df$GOOD_Outcome[i1] <- with(df[i1,], column1 == 'Y' & column2 != 'N' & column3 != "" & column4 != 'N' & column5 != ''', 'Yes', 'No'))`

Comment: Not sure what this means and what to do next.Warning message:
In df$GOOD_Outcome[i1] <- with(df[i1, ], df$value %in%  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: What is the `sum(i1)`.  I assume that  the `yourvec` is a vector of values

Comment: 33. How do i then apply it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add `ifelse` `with(df[i1,], ifelse(column1 == 'Y' & column2 != 'N' & column3 != "" & column4 != 'N' & column5 != ''', 'Yes', 'No'))`

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in " df$GOOD_OUTCOME[i1] <- ifelse with" . Not sure why i have on ifelse with(df[i1,],

Comment: I meant the code as `with(df[i1,], ifelse(column1 == 'Y' & column2 != 'N' & column3 != "" & column4 != 'N' & column5 != ''', 'Yes', 'No'))`

Comment: Warning message:
In df$GOOD_OUTCOME[i1] <- with(df[i1, ], ifelse(df$patrol_borough %in%  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Your code in the post and the code you are now showing is different.  i.e. in the post, you had only a single dataset `df`, now you are showing another data `STOP_AUDIT`

Comment: i use df to remove context of the dataset itself.

Comment: In your edited posted, you are again doing `df$`.  I used `with` so that you don't have to specify `df$` and the `with(df[i1,]` is subsetted data whereas if you again do `df$patrol..`, this extracts the whole column instead of subsetted with `i1`